# Is it possible to detect the removal of a reaction?

Tags: discord.js

I know you can detect the addition of a new reaction but using a [`ReactionCollector`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector). But is it possible to detect the removal of a reaction?

I know i could keeping track of all reactions in a DB, and continuously poll the discord api and compare the DB version to the live version. But I'd rather not do this if there's a better solution out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the discord.js API has [an event you can listen for: `messageReactionRemove`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionRemove). You have to maintain a message cache, because it only fires for messages in your cache. You fill out your cache using [`fetchMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a event for this, called 'messageReactionRemove' to see if someone removes a reaction.
This is a simple example for a reaction role bot i have:

```
const events = {
    MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE: 'messageReactionRemove',
};
```

Then you can make for instance an if statement, and ask for the `MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE`

```
if (event.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE") member.addRole(guildRole.id);
```